# Angular UI Tab's Select event is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [Angular UI Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) as shown below.My issue here is the inner `uib-tabset`  `select` event is being fired on `load` moment.In other words without clicking that tab (`heading="sorry"`).Can you tell me how to sort out this issue?

Here is the [**Plunker.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPjiIFkLAIJ6bQslcPNb)

```
 <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">
      <uib-tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </uib-tab-heading>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </uib-tab>

     <uib-tab heading="My issue">
        <uib-tabset type="pills">
            <uib-tab heading="sorry" select="alertMe()">

            </uib-tab>

        </uib-tabset>
     </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the active attribute of the inner, nested uib-tabset to null. By default the first tab is always selected hence the alertMe function is executed.

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">
    <uib-tab-heading>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
    </uib-tab-heading>
    I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
  </uib-tab>

  <uib-tab heading="My issue">
    <uib-tabset type="pills" active="null">
      <uib-tab heading="sorry" select="alertMe()">

      </uib-tab>

    </uib-tabset>
  </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OqfsBzlwTe4zoq5UmHEw?p=preview)

**OP's feedback :** For me `active="-1"` worked.

Comment: Wow..Excellent..Thanks a lot :D